# Edit "System Tray" in LDXE taskbar

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, system-tray, taskbar, preferences

Using Lubuntu here and I would love to remove icons from my system tray. Will `dconf-editor` work on LDXE as well as Unity (Ubuntu)? Or are there any other solutions to modify the taskbar?

When I go to right-click on the taskbar to bring up the Panel Settings under the "Panel Applets" tab, the "Edit" button for the System Tray is greyed out.

[image]

Any way of organizing and removing icons from the System Tray is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are in the right area.  What are you trying to remove and what are you trying rearrange?

Comment: @Rex I'm trying to remove Steam's icon, and just wondering if the icons can be rearranged.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Steam icon is a quick launch icon it is under the very first "Application Launch Bar" in Panel Preferences.  Navigate to that and click it.  Choose edit and do whatever you want to do; delete, up, down.  This is also the place where you add an icon of an application that you have installed.  For more information on menus, look at http://lxlinux.com/#9